# numpy apply_along_axis vectorisation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to implement a function that takes each row in a numpy 2d array and returns me scalar result of a certain calculations. My current code looks like the following:

```
img = np.array([
    [0,  5,  70, 0,  0,  0 ],
    [10, 50, 4,  4,  2,  0 ],
    [50, 10, 1,  42, 40, 1 ], 
    [10, 0,  0,  6,  85, 64],
    [0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  90]]
)

def get_y(stride):
    stride_vals = stride[stride > 0]
    pix_thresh = stride_vals.max() - 1.5*stride_vals.std()
    return np.argwhere(stride>pix_thresh).mean()

np.apply_along_axis(get_y, 0, img)
>> array([ 2. ,  1. ,  0. ,  2. ,  2.5,  3.5])
```

It works as expected, however, performance isn't great as in real dataset there are ~2k rows and ~20-50 columns for each frame, coming 60 times a second.

Is there a way to speed-up the process, perhaps by not using `np.apply_along_axis` function?

Comment: I expect apply_along_axis to be slower than a simple row iteration.

Comment: @hpaulj I tested it and it is indeed slightly slower to row iteration when it comes to speed. Is there any particular reason for that? If apply along axis is generally slower than row iteration, what is the point of having such function?

Comment: Convenience.  It is Python code, which you can read.  It doesn't compile either the loop or the evaluation of your function.  It just generalizes the loop, making it easier to express evaluation over multiple dimensions (i.e. the other 3 of a 4d array).  It uses `np.ndindex` to generate the loop indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach setting the `zeros` as `NaN` and that let's us use `np.nanmax` and `np.nanstd` to compute those `max` and `std` values avoiding the `zeros`, like so -

```
imgn = np.where(img==0, np.nan, img)
mx = np.nanmax(imgn,0) # np.max(img,0) if all are positive numbers
st = np.nanstd(imgn,0)
mask = img > mx - 1.5*st
out = np.arange(mask.shape[0]).dot(mask)/mask.sum(0)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [94]: img = np.random.randint(-100,100,(2000,50))

In [95]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(get_y, 0, img)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.36 ms per loop

In [96]: %%timeit
    ...: imgn = np.where(img==0, np.nan, img)
    ...: mx = np.nanmax(imgn,0)
    ...: st = np.nanstd(imgn,0)
    ...: mask = img > mx - 1.5*st
    ...: out = np.arange(mask.shape[0]).dot(mask)/mask.sum(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop
```

Thus, we are seeing a `3x+` speedup.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. For larger images, it gives 100x+ speedup!